# Two frames show up at the same time

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, joptionpane

I am a new programmer, a student, i am very new to swing. I have a two classes entitled **GUImath.java** which is the menu, and the **joption.java** . For a context, I was developing this silly little program because I want to advance a little bit from our class and you have to run the **joption.java** first before the **GUImath.java**. My problem is in the end of the **joption.java** there is a choice that prompts the user to save changes after the **GUImath.java** closed but my problem is that the **GUImath.java** and the choice from **joption.java** launches their screen at the same time.

**GUImath**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GUImath implements ActionListener {

    static JTextField Num1txt, Num2txt, Sum;
    static JLabel Title, Num1lbl, Num2lbl, Sumlbl, UserInfo;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Math");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        joption AutSection = new joption();
        String name = AutSection.name;
        String school = AutSection.school;

        panel.setLayout(null);

        JButton Calculate;
        JButton Exit = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Exit") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        Exit.setBounds(300, 250, 80, 25);

        //Labels
        Title = new JLabel("Welcome to the calculator! ");
        Title.setBounds(220, 3, 180, 25);
        UserInfo = new JLabel(name + ", from " + school + " using");
        UserInfo.setBounds(150, 15, 700, 30);
        Num1lbl = new JLabel("Number 1:");
        Num1lbl.setBounds(50, 50, 80, 25);
        Num2lbl = new JLabel("Number 2: ");
        Num2lbl.setBounds(290, 50, 80, 25);
        Sumlbl = new JLabel("Sum: ");
        Sumlbl.setBounds(210, 100, 80, 25);

        //textfields
        Num1txt = new JTextField(10);
        Num1txt.setBounds(120, 50, 80, 25);
        Num2txt = new JTextField(10);
        Num2txt.setBounds(370, 50, 80, 25);
        Sum = new JTextField("", 5);
        Sum.setBounds(250, 100, 80, 25);

        //Buttons
        Calculate = new JButton("Calculate");
        Calculate.setBounds(170, 250, 100, 25);
        Calculate.addActionListener(new GUImath());

        panel.add(Title);
        panel.add(UserInfo);

        panel.add(Num1lbl);
        panel.add(Num1txt);

        panel.add(Num2lbl);
        panel.add(Num2txt);

        panel.add(Sumlbl);
        panel.add(Sum);

        panel.add(Calculate);
        panel.add(Exit);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(Num1txt.getText());
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(Num2txt.getText());

        int sum = num1 + num2;
        Sum.setText(String.valueOf(sum));



    }
}
```

**joption.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class joption {
    static String name;
    static String school;
    static int choice;
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Program();
        while (choice == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
            Program();
        }


    }
    static void Program () {

        int firstchoice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Welcome to Vie étudiante, Do you want to Proceed? ", "Vie étudiante", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (firstchoice == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your Name: ");
        if (name == null) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        school = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your School: ");
        if (school == null) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        String age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your Age: ");
        if (age == null) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        int num = Integer.parseInt(age);

        //age checker student must be 13 above
        while (num < 13) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Age not suitable! Must be 13 and above", "Age Not Suitable", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your Age: "));
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello " + name + " from " + school + ", Great You're in, Please press OK to proceed");

        GUImath.main(new String[] {});


        choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to save changes?", "Confirm", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

What I really wanted is that I wanted the choice save changes to launch after the **GUImath** class/frame is closed. I am sorry for the bad english, not my first language. Also I am new to swing please dont be meaaan :)))

Comment: You look to be desiring to display a ***modal*** window, one that blocks code flow until it has been dealt with and is no longer visible. With Java Swing you would do this by creating and displaying a *modal JDialog* not by displaying a JFrame which is inherently non-modal. One example of a modal JDialog is a JOptionPane, but non-JOptionPane dialogs are also commonly used.

Comment: Having said this, I do recommend that you check out the link: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636). Also, this code could be much better written, even without the GUI considerations by first creating a decent object oriented programming (OOP) design. This includes that you should have only one main method, that it should be small, and that it should only serve to create your main objects and set them running, and that's it.

Comment: Also, as long as you are making windows, why bother with throwing a bunch of single-question JOptionPanes at the user. Much better would be to consolidate the question and response fields into a single window.